# Migrate Web Forms presentation layer to React

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

Is it possible to embed a completely separate stand-alone React project in a ASP.NET Web Forms project? Hoping to avoid iFrame though.

**Details**:

We have a legacy ASP.NET Web Forms application, and are looking to migrate our presentation layer (.ascx controls) to React. We are looking to create a **completely separate stand-alone React project**, and re-write one screen at a time from ASCX Web Forms controls to React.

Once each screen is we-written in the React project, we would like to have it embedded in the Web Forms project so the user has a seamless transition.

For example, screen 1 would be a Web Forms control, but if a user clicks a button to go to screen 2, that screen would be a React control behind the scenes?

We thought about using an ***iFrame***, but are hoping there are better approaches.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: React can use any HTML element [as the root](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render), so yeah, why not? You'd probably just bundle the project and set an ID for whichever element you want to mount your app on and load the bundled script on the relevant page.

Comment: Our legacy web forms app is in Visual Studio and the React project is in Visual Studio Code. What would be a good way to bundle the projects since they are developed in separate IDEs.